# Passing the fermat test

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ where ${\rm gcd}(b,~p)=1$. Prove that $b$ passes the Fermat test test for $m=p^2$ if and only if $b^{p-1}\equiv1$ mod $p^2$.

---

We show this is true in both directions. Suppose $b$ passes the Fermat test, so that

$$a^{b-1} \equiv 1~{\rm mod}~b,$$

What does $m=p^2$ mean? How do I continue this proof?

Comment: It's not particularly well phrased. What you are meant to show is that $$b^{p^2-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2} \iff b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer How did you obtain the LHS?

Comment: Plug $m = p^2$ into $b^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

Comment: Where did you obtain $b^{m-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $m$)?

Comment: That's the Fermat test for base $b$ and possible prime $m$. While usually one would say that $m$ passes the Fermat test with base $b$ when $b^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, here the authors say that the base $b$ passes the test in that case.

Comment: But the Fermat test states $p$ is prime for $0<a<p$ if $a^{p-1} \equiv 1~({\rm mod}~p)$. This doesn't conclude anything about $a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sketch of a proof. Assume that $$b^{p^{2}-1} \equiv 1 \quad \pmod{p^{2}}$$
then since $p$ is prime we can write $b^{p} \equiv b \pmod{p}$, or alternatively
$$b^{p} = jp+b$$
for some integer $j$.

Then move to the binomial theorem,
\begin{align}
b^{p^{2}}&=(jp+b)^{p} \\
         &= b^{p}+\binom{p}{p-1}pb^{p-1}jp+\binom{p}{p-2}b^{p-2}j^{2}p^{2}+\ldots
\end{align}
Every term on the right hand side here contains a factor of $p^{2}$, other than $b^{p}$. Hence
$$b^{p} \equiv b^{p^{2}} \quad \pmod{p^{2}}$$
this is equivalent to saying
\begin{align}
b^{p-1} &\equiv b^{p^{2}-1} \\
        &\equiv 1 \quad \pmod{p^{2}}
\end{align}
**Quick Edit** By the way, we can take this last step (i.e, dividing by $b$) since $\gcd(b, p)=1$

Comment: You state since $p$ is prime we can write $b^p\equiv b~({\rm mod}~p^2)$, how is this true? Also your next step you state $b^p = jp +b$, should this be $b^p=jp^2+b$?

Comment: @user2850514 Good spot - I have changed the $\pmod{p^{2}}$ to $\pmod{p}$ which then means we can write, wlog $b^{p}=jp+b$. Many thanks.